# Silverlight TreeGrid/TreeList functionality

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, treeview

I have a requirement for a "Tree grid" or "Tree list" control.

This is something that looks like a DataGrid, but the left hand side is a tree that can be expanded and collapsed to show different rows (typically grouped, or perhaps showing data from a heirarchy).

Has anyone tried to build something like this by hand? If so do you recommend that route?

Or am I better of buying the control? If so who sells a good one?

We are targetting Silverlight 4 if that makes a difference

**UPDATE:** This is the type of [control](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/wpf/grid/minimal-gtc) I am looking for (but for SL obviously)

Comment: looks like i will be writing my own at this rate...

Comment: Our official version of RadTreeListView will be very similar to RadGridView and will be available for both WPF and Silverlight. You can check this thread on our forums for more info: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/gridview/hierarchy-relations-and-column-line-up.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://blogs.perpetuumsoft.com/silverlight/how-to-turn-silverlight-datagrid-to-treegrid-in-15-minutes/) looks promising.  He uses a DataGrid with a custom data source and cell template.  This is the only example I have found so far that actually ends up looking like a DataGrid (because it is one).

Telerik has a [CTP of a TreeListView control](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#TreeListView/FirstLook), but it definitely looks more like a list than a data grid.

Also see this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920242/looking-for-tree-grid-control-for-silverlight) also on StackOverflow.