# Looking for Tree Grid control for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Quick question:

Is it somewhere available - preferably free / opensource or at reasonable price?

**EDIT**

To be more precise, there's an example of winforms control (SandGrid from Divelements) what I'm looking for. Forming a tree is important, grouping by isn't necessary.

[alt text http://www.divelements.com/net/controls/sandgrid/home1.gif](http://www.divelements.com/net/controls/sandgrid/home1.gif)

Answer (score 1):

[Vectorlight](http://www.vectorlight.net) has a nice [set of opensource Silveright controls](http://www.vectorlight.net/controls.aspx) ([TreeView included](http://www.vectorlight.net/controls/tree_view.aspx) ) they also have some silverlight tutorials. To download the dlls you must be registered (for free).

If you need the source code, use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/index.htm).

Answer (score 1):

On Codeplex you can find a treelist/treegrid control. Unfortunately it is under the GPL2 Licence.
http://multicolumntreelist.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can find a TreeMap and a TreeView for free in the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com).
The Silverlight 4 DataGrid will have [Grouping Support](http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/Silverlight4/EmployeeManager/) as well.

Comment: OK but I need a single control which looks exactly like a Datagrid but allows me to nest rows like in a tree. I can't see this behaviour in SL Toolkit

Comment: The Silverlight 4 DataGrid will have Grouping Support.

Comment: I'm not looking for grouping support.

Answer (score 0):

The Telerik suite has just what you need, the TreeListView:

- http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#TreeListView/FirstLook
- http://www.liquidjelly.co.uk/supersearch/?q=telerik%20silverlight%20treelistview&lang=en-GB

Note: this control is currently in CTP, and unfortunately it's not *that* cheap.